# Is there any official "Ask Ubuntu" color defined?

Tags: discussion, design

I´m planning to add the "Ask" logo into [the `simple-icons` project](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/), in the hope of contributing to the growing collection of [the](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/blob/develop/icons/superuser.svg) [stack](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/blob/develop/icons/serverfault.svg) [exchange](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/blob/develop/icons/stackoverflow.svg) [network](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/blob/develop/icons/stackexchange.svg) icons.
Things are, I haven't found a defined official color yet. [Quoting myself](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/issues/5095#issue-812981075), what I've found so far:

- [`#dd4c00`](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/Img/apple-touch-icon.png) [image]
- [`#f47323`](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png) [image]
- `#dc461d` in the [logo's topbar](https://askubuntu.com)

One of the maintainers of the project have made [his own research on this topic](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/issues/5095#issuecomment-783776572), but he's also not clear on this and suggested to ask here.
So... any official advise on this matter?

Comment: Here is the official colours of Ubuntu https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette/ Once up on a time, this site used the official colours but that seems to have stopped since the network design changed. If I was you, I would just use the proper Ubuntu colours and not worry too much about the sites colours.

Comment: @MarkKirby I think your comment is well worthy of being an answer :)

Answer (score 10):

As far as I am aware there is no official "Ask Ubuntu" colours, however, before the change to [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-released-for-all-beta-undesigned-sites), this site did use the official Ubuntu colour scheme.

Rather than be concerned about the sites colours or the colour of icons found online, I would recommend for you to use the official Ubuntu colours [listed here](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette/). The "Ubuntu orange" is very much something people recognize as part of the brand.

Ubuntu orange: HEX #E95420

[image: Ubuntu Orange HEX #E95420]